# In my webview upload image button not working but in browser it's working?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

In my webview upload image button not working but on browser it's working good but not in my webview app? My app is in Kotlin not Java. Anybody know how to solve this issue. I just want to upload an image by this button.

on browser image:
[image: on browser image]

**mainactivity.kt**

```
package com.little.example
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.webkit.WebBackForwardList
    import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
    import android.webkit.WebView
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient
    import com.little.example.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity
    import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.ExtraData
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
    import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T




    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            webview.loadUrl("https://little.com")
             webview.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()



    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()){
            webview.goBack()
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if (!url.contains("little.com")) {//for example
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                startActivity(intent)
                return true
            }

            view.loadUrl(url)
            return false

        }}

}
```

Comment: Please don't do this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60611575. One copy of the question is sufficient, especially when it's still on the front page.

Comment: Without the web page in question, we have no way of debugging this (the URL in the code does not resolve).

Answer (score 0):

please add into your `Webview` settings, below the `webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true`:

```
 webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```